# Nestjs @ResolveField decorator triggered in for one metod only

Tags: graphql, nestjs

Simplifying - I've got 2 methods in my resolver, that I'd expect to use the same field decorator, but only one does. Is that because of different types? If so, how to solve this issue?

```
@Resolver(() => Project) // <----  Type: Project
export class ProjectResolver {
  constructor(....)
  
  @Roles(Role.User)
  @UseGuards(RoleGuard)
  @Query(() => [ProjectDetails]) // <---- Type: [ProjectDetails]
  async getProjects() {
    return await this.getProjects();
  }
  // when the above is called, resolvers are not triggered

  // but when this is called, it is triggered
  @Roles(Role.User)
  @UseGuards(RoleGuard)
  @Query(() => [Project])) // <---- type: Project
  async getMyProjects(userId) {
    return await this.ProjectRepository.getMyProjects(userId);
  }

  @ResolveField()
  async startDate(@Root() Project: Project): Promise<Date | null> {
    return await this.getProjectStartDate(Project);
  }

  @ResolveField()
  async endDate(@Root() Project: Project): Promise<Date | null> {
    return await getProjectEndDate(Project);
  }
  
}
```

`ProjectDetails` extends `Project` so that's why this landed in the same resolver class, among few more methods regarding both types

Comment: I'd guess that even though one extends another, they are still two different GraphQL classes. Have you tried extracting a common class `ProjectBase`, use it in the field resolvers, and then extend it by those two?

Comment: I've split those in 2 different classes extending ProjectBase with those 2 fields. I had to add the @Resolve decorator to the class and define the return type function, so I've used `Project` there and it works. Tank you